# Какие коды ошибок возвращать в rest?

Tags: java, http, rest

В задании написано вернуть коды ошибок типичные для rest. Какие именно? Какие коды являются типичными для rest?

Comment: Думаю имеются ввиду коды ошибок HTTP

Comment: Это типичные ошибки HTTP протокола. Вот просмотрите здесь есть подобное описание ошибок http://www.restapitutorial.ru/httpstatuscodes.html или же в википедии можете почитать по этой ссылке [Список кодов состояния HTTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Типичные для REST это ошибки

200 - успешные

400 - ошибки на стороне клиента

500 - ошибки на стороне сервера

Comment: Выше сказали что те 10 обрабатывать, а вы говорите о трёх. Как лучше?

Comment: я написал в общем))А выше описали какие конкретно из этих групп лучше описать)

Comment: Вам тоже спасибо) и тоже вопрос, не подскажите как это сделать в плане spring boot?))

Comment: Вы бы кусок кода кинули)) А вообще вам надо создать рест контроллер, которые будут возвращать вам эти ошибки

Comment: Хммм, есть рест контроллер. Который просто возвращает json и все. То есть метод get и аннотации restcontroller и requestmapping... Если надо по точнее то через минут 40 буду дома скину...

Comment: если рест контроллер возвращает вам json то запрос успешен, то есть код будет 200, если вы например укажете неправильный url, то будет 404 ошибка, т.к. страница не существует. Если вы сделаете запрос, не запустив локальный сервер, то будет 500 ошибка. А вообще мы можете свой контроллер на ошибки с помощью HttpStatus.

Comment: Уххх, неправильный урл это то есть такой который на существует? Есть урл к примеру...rest/filter?tyyty=random.... Random это типо значения фильтра по которым идёт запрос в базу и это все что может делать апи.... То есть при таком раскладе когда в запросе будет отсутствовать слово filter тогда и надо просто отдать 404?

Comment: например у вас замаплен урл = localhost:5432/users/getAll. Если вы в Postman или Curl проверите его и вместо getAll напишите users/getAli, то будет 404 ошибка(страница не найдена)

Comment: Тут у меня есть такой нюанс, для этого использовать responseentity?  Как это можна по правильнее сделать?

Comment: @JohhnyBravo Что будет лучше применить?

Comment: Используйте response entity и httpstatus, который может выкинуть ту или иную ошибку

Comment: А нужно ли передавать какой-то json?

Comment: «успешные ошибки» это что-то новое.